# check if daylight savings time moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So I'm having an issue with daylight savings time and the .isDST() flag..

So I have a time selector where a user can set a start time right then I take the two number vaues (hour and minute) and convert that into a moment object like so..

```
this.startTime = moment(`${this.hour}:${this.minute} ${this.timeOfDay}`, `hh:mm a`).utc();
```

now that saves all fine but when I get that returned its an hour out because of daylight savings time.. now Im aware of the flag .isDST() but I'm not sure where I can set it.

Ive tried

```
this.startTime = moment(`${this.hour}:${this.minute} ${this.timeOfDay}`, `hh:mm a`).utc().isDST();
```

but that returns an invalid date and I've also tried on the return..

```
time = moment(startTime).local().format('hh:mm').isDST(); 
time = moment(startTime).isDST().local().format('hh:mm');
time = moment(startTime).local().isDST().format('hh:mm');
```

but no of those work either ...

what is the correct way to deal with this issue?

**EDIT**

To clarify.. how do I used the .isDST() in the official docs it just says `moment().isDST();` so How Do I check if the `local` time that Ive converted from `utc` is `DST` and then format it correctly

Comment: How can UTC ever be DST? Consider posting a working snippet to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @RobG sorry to clarify on the return its not converting it to the DST, so Im not sure where to put the flag? as I set the time or when I receive the time?

Comment: It's very unclear what your issue is. Moment.js is based on the built-in Date object. When given a time, *moment.js* uses the current date, the Date constructor will use the host timezone offset to generate a UTC time value. You say "*when I get that returned*" but not from what. You need to post an example that displays the issue, what you have so far just isn't enough.

Answer (score 3):

This shows how it works. You just need to use isDST() on a moment with a local() or a specific timezone where DST is applicable. I don't think it'll work on a hh:mm only. You might need an actual date (time optional) to find if it's DST or not.

```js
console.log(moment().utc().isDST());
console.log(moment().tz("America/New_York").isDST());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes will need to know the actual date & timezone it's being converted into. As DST only runs between certain dates in certain timezones.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1208) they say that UTC is never DST. So `moment('anything...').utc().isDST()` will always return false.

Next - judging by the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-daylight-saving-time/), isDST does not set anything, it's a getter method that returns true if the time corresponds to DST period and false otherwise.

Don't know for sure how to fix your problem, but maybe [utcOffset](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) can help. If you see that the time is not right, add/substract 1 hour there and it should work out.